# Add html tags in note field of product attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

```
eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
                ...
                'note'=>'<strong>Product Attribute Info</strong>'
            ]
        );
```

But the strong tags appearing as string. How to get it printed as HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below way it would be work.

```
eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sample Atrribute',
                ...
                'note'=>'<![CDATA[<strong>Product Attribute Info</strong>]]>'
            ]
        );
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Already tried it, it prints everything as string.